# UICollectionViewをスクロールすると描画が重なってしまう

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

UICollectionViewにUILabel、UIImageViewを描画しています。
cellForItemAtIndexPathでaddSubViewしているUILabelが
スクロールするたびに重なってしまう現象で悩んでいます。

※UICollectionView自体はStoryboard上にあり、ReuseIdentifierを設定しています。

subviewを削除するように入れてみても重なってしまいます。
どこか間違っていますでしょうか？
アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UICollectionViewCell * cell;
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"newscell";
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

for (UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
   [view removeFromSuperview];

}

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

//ここに各Viewのframeなどを設定するコード(割愛)

[cell addSubview:titleLabel];
[cell addSubview:dateLabel];
[cell addSubview:textLabel];
return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//ここに各Viewのframeなどを設定するコード(割愛)

// [cell addSubview:titleLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubView: titleLabel];
// [cell addSubview:dateLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubView: dateLabel];
// [cell addSubview:textLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubView: textLabel];
return cell;

}
```

このように変更したら、どうなりますか？

Comment: できました！！！！！！！！！
見逃していました。。的確なご指摘、本当に感謝いたします。
ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 2):

-cellForItemAtIndexPath: の中で -addSubview: するのをそもそもやめた方がいいと思います。
UICollectionViewCell のサブクラスを作成し、サブクラスの初期化時にラベルを生成、プロパティとしましょう。
そうすることで subviews を removeFromSuperview する余計な処理もいらなくなります。

上記を行った上で -cellForItemAtIndexPath: の中で行うのは「ラベルの表示内容の変更」としましょう。

Comment: ソース中では割愛しているのですが、このような実装に至った経緯は、サーバから取得したタイトル/日付/本文/画像(ありorなし)によりUICollectionViewCellの配置が異なるため、都度frameを指定する必要があったからです。Autolayout+UILabelのsizetoFitでは上手くいかず、しょうがなくcellForItemAtIndexPathで計算し配置するという手段に至りました。。サブクラスを作っても出来そうですので、そちらでも作ってみようと思います。アドバイスありがとうございます。